# How to hide navigation bar on Android app Built Using Cordova?

Tags: javascript, android, cordova, cordova-plugins, navigationbar

How do we hide the navigation bar on android or customize it on cordova , Can anyone suggest?

Comment: what navigation bar are you talking about?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding the following to your `config.xml` file inside the **android platform element**

```
<preference name="Fullscreen" value="true" />
```

Comment: Where inside config.xml do I put it?

Comment: @Chris anywhere inside the android platform element

Answer (score 0):

you should be able to just remove the nav section, but if you want to do it in javascript, change the style to display:none.  in jquery: `$("nav").hide();`